# upload task getDownloadUrl() after completion

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I need this general purpose utility method that accepts the file object and return me the url of the file after uploading, but some how I am getting a promise instead of the download URL.

I have tried all approached, i need ES6 `async/await` solution.

```js
export const uploadFile = (file) => {
  let uploadTask = storage.ref(`products/${Date.now()}.${file.name.split('.').pop()}`).put(file);
  uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, {
    'complete': () => {
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((d) => {
        return d
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the doc, if you call [`then()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) on a `UploadTask`, you will get an object which "behaves like a Promise, and resolves with its snapshot data when the upload completes".

Therefore the following should do the trick.

```
export const uploadFile = (file) => {
  let uploadTask = storage.ref(`products/${Date.now()}.${file.name.split('.').pop()}`).put(file);
  return uploadTask.
    then(snapshot => {
      return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .then((url) => {
      return url
    });
}
```

---

**Update following your comment:**

You mention in the comments that you call the function as follows:

```
let files = state.images; 
for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
   files = files.concat(e.target.files[i]); 
   let url = uploadFile(files[i])
   console.log(url)
}
```

However, the `uploadFile()` function **is asynchronous** and indeed, as a consequence, it returns a Promise. You should take that into account when calling it. For example, with a loop, you could call it as follows:

```
const promises = [];
let files = state.images; 
for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
   files = files.concat(e.target.files[i]); 
   promises.push(uploadFile(files[i]));
}
Promise.all(promises)
 .then(urlsArray => {
    urlsArray.forEach(url => {
        console.log(url);
    })
  })
```

Comment: See the update, I had forgotten to return the promises chain.

Comment: I already tried these combination before asking the question it still return the proimse. here is the response i am getting.

`Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseValue]]: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.../o/products%2F1596413026802.jpg"`

Comment: How do you call the function? Can you show the code?

Comment: `let files = state.images;`
`for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {`
`files = files.concat(e.target.files[i]);`
`let url = uploadFile(files[i])`
 `console.log(url)`
 `}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I understood my mistake.
My apologies for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 async await solution for others having similar problem:

```js
export const uploadFile = async (file) => {
  let uploadTask = storage.ref(`products/${Date.now()}.${file.name.split('.').pop()}`).put(file);
  const snapshot = await uploadTask;
  const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}
```